# Matlab : open OS explorer window only if not already open

Tags: matlab, explorer

I'm opening a folder in Windows explorer from within matlab with the following line :

```
system('explorer.exe /select,./my_folder/my_file.tif');
```

It works well, even with the relative path for Matlab "current folder" with "./". Note that it also selects the specified file, which is what I want.

However, I would like to open this window only if the same path isn't already open. Right now, I get several copies of the same window and it's annoying. Do you know any way to do this ?

Thanks,

Ghislain

(Windows 8, Matlab R2011b 64bits)

Comment: Hmm... That's a tough one. I tried playing with `'system(start c:\folder')`, because executing `start` in a CMD prompt only opens one window. But no luck. It might work by invoking some DDE magic, but it's virtually impossible to find information about that, because "DDE has been outdated for well over a decade". But internally, windows uses it all over the place - for instance, when executing `start`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This is a partial answer. I don't know how to go on from here, but maybe it helps anyways. Your question is quite interesting to me, and it would make data-analysis a lot easier if changing between interfaces (Matlab/Explorer) were easier!

**Some History**

DDE is an ancient technology (16-bit Windows, yeah!) that enables Windows applications to talk to each other. DDE has been deperecated from Windows XP on, but it simply refuses to die.

One reason for DDE's longevity is that Windows Explorer still uses DDE a lot. For example, when you double-click a file, the Explorer sends a DDE command to Excel, telling it to open that file in the current Excel window.

**How DDE might help you**

Matlab's DDE support is officially deprecated. Maybe it would have disappeared completely, were it not for the fact that Explorer talks to Matlab via DDE messages!

You can reverse this process by telling initiating a DDE channel to the application "folders" about the topic "appproperties":

```
channel = ddeinit('folders', 'appproperties')
```

The "folders" application appears to be a synonym for "progman", the good ol' Windows 3 program manager. You can tell Explorer ("folders") to view a folder by executing

```
ddeexec(channel, '[ViewFolder("%l", c:\windows, 5)]')
```

If Explorer already points to that folder, no new window is opened. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you much more about that command. I don't know what that %l is doing there, or the 5 for that matter. The only thing I know is that ViewFolder can be replaced by ExploreFolder, in which case you always open a new window, and that window always shows the folder tree structure on the left pane.

**More Information**

The most important DDE-related functions are ddeinit, ddeexec, and ddeterm. Their documentation is buried inside the .m files of those functions. You can view the .m files by simply executing

```
edit ddeinit
```

Yair Altman has [some more info](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-dde-support) on Matlab's DDE capabilities. What DDE commands are understdood by Explorer evades me. I assembled my example from what I found [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/996).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! It seems I can't use the relative path anymore (which is not a problem) and I didn't find out how to pre-select a given file as in the example in my question. It's not a big deal but if anyone finds more options for "ViewFolder"... tell us !

Comment: Also, sometimes the folder window opens but doesn't appear on top of other windows (only the taskbar explorer icon twinkles). It doesn't happen every time, I don't find a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Hmm... DDE might be too limited for this task. I've been trying to figure out how you could use COM or .NET to do the same thing, but I just can't figure out how to talk to a File Explorer Window with them.