# Does Windows File Explorer have a COM or .NET interface?

Tags: .net, matlab, com, windows-explorer

I want to control the state of a File Explorer window programmatically (using Matlab). Specifically, I would like to change the window state (minimized, maximized, pop to foreground), change the folder that is currently viewed, and maybe preselect a file.

I know that I can open File Explorer through `system` calls, but I don't want to open a new window every time. I am also aware of the [limited control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885128) that [DDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) offers. But DDE is horribly outdated, even worse documented, and Matlab has better support for COM and .NET interfaces than for DDE.

Does the File Explorer expose COM or .NET interfaces? If so, where can I find out about them? Especially knowing the PROGID of File Explorer would help a lot.

I searched online, but COM and .NET are not easily searchable - not even on the Windows Developer search (the top results are all domains ending in .com and .net ...)

**Update:**

Thanks to the information given so far, I was able to start a new Explorer Window using

```
h_s = actxserver('shell.application');
h_s.Explore('c:\Users')
```

But I fail to see how this would allow me to *manipulate* the Explorer window. As far as I understand the documentation, the shell.application object allows me to interact with the shell, not with File Explorer. I did not find a method that allows me to change the selected file. Also, everytime I call `h.Explore()`, a new window is opened.

As an alternative, by poking around the registry (I looked for keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT that have "sub-keys" called CLSID) I found the progID of Internet Explorer, but navigating to a file URI does not work. Instead I windows opens an Internet Explorer window and a new File Explorer window that shows the wrong location.

```
h_e = actxserver('InternetExplorer.Application')
h_e.Navigate('file:///C:/Users')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The Windows Shell has a number of interfaces (and they're easily searchable) but whether you need them depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe some info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg314982(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the links! But as far as I understand them, they only tell me how to use COM through the abstraction layer provided by the appropriate C++ libraries and header files. Under this abstraction layer, the progID seems to be hidden - at least to me!

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What does "manipulate the explorer window" means?

Comment: I want to change the window state (minimized, maximized, pop to foreground), change the folder that is currently viewed, and preselect a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost two years later, I had quite a similar (if less ambitious) goal: from Matlab, I wanted to record the current paths in all the File Explorer windows. The code below works for me (and perhaps can be extended to do additional manipulations):

```
explorer = actxserver('Shell.Application');    
windows = explorer.Windows;
nWins = windows.Count;
for iWin = 1:nWins
    w1 = windows.Item(int32(iWin-1));    % Item is zero-based
    URL = w1.get('LocationURL');         % https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    if isequal(lower(URL(1:5)), 'file:') % File Explorer window
        if isequal(URL(6:8), '///')      % Local file
            pn = URL(9:end);
        else
            pn = URL(6:end);             % Remote file
        end
        pn = strrep(pn, '/', '\');       % I'm a Windows guy
        pn = strrep(pn, '%20', ' ');     % ...and a WYSIWYG guy
    elseif isequal(lower(URL(1:5)), 'http:')
        pn = URL;                        % Internet Explorer Window
    end
    disp(pn)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `w1.Navigate2('file:///C:/stuff')` I can navigate, but maximizing/minimizing still does not work. However, I can use `w1.get('HWND')` and a [WindowAPI submission on the FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi) for these interactions.

Comment: @MartinJ.H., Your workaround does the job but it seemed a bit too low level for my taste, so I tested which methods/properties of the w1 object seem to work (besides the Navigate2 which you discovered) and which don't. I found that `w1.TheaterMode = true;` kind of maximizes the window (with a somewhat weird look), provided that the window is visible (i.e. not minimized) in the first place. Also, `w1.set('Height', 600);` and `w1.set('Width', 800)` work for re-sizing, but _only_ if the window is visible.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. On the other hand, `w1.Resizable = false;` or `w1.Resizable = true;` always work, even if the window is minimized. On top of it, I don't quite get when a property can be used with the dot notation (like Resizable), and when one has to use the w1.get('SomeProperty'), or w1.set('SomeProperty', value) notation.Go figure...

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Shell has hundreds of interfaces to work with, and you don't need a progid to work with a COM interface.

However, for Automation clients (scripting, VB, etc.), it has also specially crafted ones: [Scriptable Shell Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that are easier to use for those languages. I suppose they also work quite well in MatLab.

For these interfaces, the mother of all progids is "**shell.application**".